# Add ability to delete posts and see deleted posts

Tags: discussion, feature-request, android-app

When I click "answered/edited/asked" near the post, I can't see an ability to delete it. Also, if my question is deleted, it won't be loaded, if I answered a question and then deleted an answer, I won't see it while viewing the question in app.

Is it worth to add feature to delete posts and see deleted posts?

Comment: You can't see deleted content because the API simply doesn't allow viewing of deleted content.

Comment: @animuson it seems to be a request for such a feature to be "added" to the API.